# how to write stored procedure in c# if it has more than 300 lines

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

how to write below stored procedure in C#

i am creating class library file. i get a situation....not to give the scirpt file to clients...so i have to create SP in c# code. I desperately want to keep it in C# assembly
Let me know is this possible

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AdjustTax]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))

DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdjustTax]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdjustTax] 

    @IN_SOPType       INT,
    @IN_SOPNo         VARCHAR(21),
    @IN_AdjustAmount  NUMERIC(19,5),
    @O_iError         INT OUTPUT  

AS

BEGIN

  DECLARE @Sequence       INT,

          @FunctionalAmt  NUMERIC(19,5),
          @OriginalAmt    NUMERIC(19,5),
          @TaxDetail      VARCHAR(30),
          @TaxAmt         NUMERIC(19,5),
          @CreditAmt      NUMERIC(19,5),
          @DexRowIDSOP    INT,
          @SOPHdrTbl      VARCHAR(20)  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SET @O_iError = 0  

    SELECT @SOPHdrTbl = RTRIM(DB_NAME()) + '.dbo.SOP10100'


    SELECT @DexRowIDSOP = DEX_ROW_ID 

      FROM SOP10100 (nolock)

        WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo


    IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tempdb..DEX_LOCK (NOLOCK) WHERE table_path_name = @SOPHdrTbl AND row_id = @DexRowIDSOP))

    BEGIN  

      SET @O_iError = 2022 

    END

    ELSE

    BEGIN   

      SET @FunctionalAmt = @IN_AdjustAmount

      SET @OriginalAmt   = @IN_AdjustAmount     

      UPDATE SOP10100 

        SET TAXAMNT  = TAXAMNT   + @FunctionalAmt,

            DOCAMNT  = DOCAMNT   + @FunctionalAmt,

            ACCTAMNT = ACCTAMNT  + @FunctionalAmt,

            ORTAXAMT = ORTAXAMT  + @OriginalAmt, 

            ORDOCAMT = ORDOCAMT  + @OriginalAmt,  

            ORACTAMT = ORACTAMT  + @OriginalAmt  

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo  

      SELECT TOP 1 @TaxDetail = TAXDTLID, @TaxAmt = STAXAMNT

        FROM SOP10105

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo

        ORDER BY LNITMSEQ


      UPDATE SOP10105

        SET STAXAMNT = STAXAMNT + @FunctionalAmt,

            ORSLSTAX = ORSLSTAX + @OriginalAmt      -- Currently the same as Functional Amount

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo 

            AND LNITMSEQ=0

            AND TAXDTLID=@TaxDetail     

      SELECT TOP 1 @Sequence = SEQNUMBR, @CreditAmt=CRDTAMNT

        FROM SOP10102

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo

            AND DISTTYPE=9 

            AND ((DEBITAMT + CRDTAMNT) = @TaxAmt) 


      IF (@CreditAmt <> 0) 
      BEGIN

        UPDATE SOP10102

          SET CRDTAMNT = CRDTAMNT + @FunctionalAmt,

              ORCRDAMT = ORCRDAMT + @OriginalAmt  

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo

            AND SEQNUMBR=@Sequence
      END

      ELSE

      BEGIN 

        UPDATE SOP10102

          SET DEBITAMT = DEBITAMT + @FunctionalAmt,

              ORDBTAMT = ORDBTAMT + @OriginalAmt    

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo

            AND SEQNUMBR=@Sequence
      END 

      SELECT TOP 1 @Sequence = SEQNUMBR, @CreditAmt=CRDTAMNT
        FROM SOP10102

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo
            AND DISTTYPE=2 AND ((DEBITAMT + CRDTAMNT) > 0.0)

      IF (@CreditAmt <> 0) 
      BEGIN
        UPDATE SOP10102

          SET CRDTAMNT = CRDTAMNT + @FunctionalAmt,
              ORCRDAMT = ORCRDAMT + @OriginalAmt   

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo
            AND SEQNUMBR=@Sequence
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN 
        UPDATE SOP10102

          SET DEBITAMT = DEBITAMT + @FunctionalAmt,

              ORDBTAMT = ORDBTAMT + @OriginalAmt   

          WHERE SOPTYPE=@IN_SOPType AND SOPNUMBE=@IN_SOPNo

            AND SEQNUMBR=@Sequence
      END            
    END

IF (@O_iError = 0)

  COMMIT TRANSACTION

ELSE

  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END

GO
```

Comment: You don't write stored procedures in C# - you write them in SQL. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is very unclear from the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Are you trying to write a CLR stored procedure? Or C# to do the same kind of operation? Basically your question is *extremely* unclear. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Oded SQLCLR allows you to write stored procedures in C#

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Yes, but it is unclear if that's what the OP is after, or a _translation_ to C# constructs in a .NET application.

Comment: Put it in a SQLCommand as a string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4956bkc.aspx and run `ExecuteNonQuery()`? A bit more info on what you need and maybe better format of the code in the question can help us help you...

Comment: If your question is "rewrite this code in C#", then you are asking way too much of this forum.  Try to do it yourself, then ask specific questions if you have trouble.  And when you do post a question, you need to explain what you are trying to do and give the structures of your tables and sample data.

Comment: i am creating class library file. i get a situation....not to give the scirpt file to clients...so i have to create sp in c# code. Let me know is this possible.

Comment: Even in compiled code, if they know what they are doing they will be able to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you write it in C# in the first place?

If you want to manage DB schema use *Visual Studio Database* project.

If you desperately want to keep it in C# assembly, create a separate .sql file, embed it as a resource and load it in C# as a string.

In file properties change *Build Action* to **Embedded Resource** and use the following code to load it

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .GetManifestResourceStream("Your assembly namespace" + "file.sql"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: yes i want to keep in assembly. i stored .sql file separate  folder in project solution.Can you explain how to embed this file.

Comment: i am getting stream value  as null. using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("TaxRoundingUtility" + "GP_SOP_AdjustTax.sql"))

Comment: `TaxRoundingUtility` is probably not your full namespace. Google examples of usage of `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`

Answer (score 0):

300 lines SP is fine, as far as it is clear and easy to understand

with large portions of SP it is better to write some comment